# What's wrong with my Vncserver setting?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, vnc-server

Holle, everyone:

I want install 'vncserver' in my ubuntu 16.04 server, but it always grey screen when I conneted via 'VNC Viewer'. I don't know what the problem is, can anyone help to solve it?
Thanks a lot!

vnaserver start log:

```
Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.1 - built Feb 25 2015 23:02:21
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40300000, The XFree86 Project, Inc

Thu Jul 19 13:38:01 2018
vncext:      VNC extension running!
vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5904
vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/, removing from list!
Error:            XKB extension not present on :4
XKB extension not present on :4
                  Exiting
Starting session: /etc/X11/Xsession
Session terminated with return code 1
```

xstartup file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#x-window-manager &

gnome-terminal &
```

change these lines as-

```
x-window-manager &

#gnome-terminal &
```

I think this should work.
Also check if gnome-panel, metacity, and nautilus packages are installed, if not install them.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
yum install gnome* xterm* xorg* -y
```